# Construct date column from year, month and day in Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars, polarssl

Consider the following Polars dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
   'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01']
})

df.with_column(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%Y-%m').cast(pl.Datetime)).alias('year-month')
```

Currently the dataframe is:

| date |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-02-01 |
| 2022-03-01 |

The desired output is:

| date | year-month |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-02 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-03 |

I have tried:

```
df.with_column(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%Y-%m').cast(pl.Datetime)).alias('year-month')
```

I get:

SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected `Utf8`, got `datetime[ns]`

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I don't think a pl.Date time can just be a year & month, it has to have a day of month as well.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to first parse it as `Date`, and then format it according to your desired format:

```py
In [9]: df.with_columns(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date)).with_columns(year_month=pl.col('date').dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
Out[9]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ date       ┆ year_month │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ str        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01    │
│ 2022-02-01 ┆ 2022-02    │
│ 2022-03-01 ┆ 2022-03    │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Note that once you format it as `%Y-%m`, it'll no longer be of `Date` dtype

Comment: It seems they already have the Date and just need the strftime part.